# Are there any open source tools to detect and fill sinks on a DEM?

Tags: grass-gis, dem, software-recommendations, open-source-gis

Are there any open source or inexpensive tools to detect and fill sinks on a DEM? ArcGIS Spatial Analyst is just out of my price range.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GRASS has [r.fill.dir](http://grass.itc.it/grass65/manuals/html65_user/r.fill.dir.html) and better yet, [r.terraflow](http://grass.itc.it/grass65/manuals/html65_user/r.terraflow.html), which is one of the few hydrology tools to work on massive rasters. There's also [TauDem](http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5.0/), which includes `PitRemove` for filling.

Comment: I've also written a piece of software, RichDEM, which has a variety of _fast_ (sometimes thousands of times faster) algorithms for depression filling and other hydrological applications. See: https://richdem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/depression_filling.html

Comment: TauDem is cross platform and works fine on Linux and OS X.

Comment: @mankoff thanks for the update, that's great. Earlier releases were Windows only (I know 3.1 was, but perhaps later versions as well). Unfortunately the download page doesn't include references to it, but I do see a PPA containing it, along with a homebrew package.

Answer (score 9):

[SAGA](http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html) has several fill methods

http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_modules_doc/ta_preprocessor/index.html

Flat Detection
Sink Drainage Route Detection
Sink Removal
Fill Sinks (Planchon/Darboux, 2001)
Fill Sinks (Wang & Liu)
Fill Sinks XXL (Wang & Liu)

Comment: Note that the Planchon & Darboux (2001) method produces the same results as Wang & Liu (2006), just much, much slower. No one should use P&D if an alternative is available. Barnes (2014), Zhou (2016), and Wei (2018) improve on the speed of Wang & Liu (2006), collectively achieving a 6x or more speed-up.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually an area of active research for me.

You can use the Priority-Flood algorithm as described by [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300413001337) journal article, which is [also](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.04463) available on arXiv. This allows you to fill depressions in *O(n log n)* time for floating-point data and *O(n)* time for integer data. Source code is available [here](https://github.com/r-barnes/Barnes2013-Depressions).

The foregoing algorithm is serial and works well up to a hundred million cells or so. Sometimes, though, your datasets are larger.

[This article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300416301704), also available [on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.06204), describes an algorithm with excellent scaling suitable for datasets of up to a trillion or more cells. Source is available [here](https://github.com/r-barnes/Barnes2016-ParallelPriorityFlood).

All of the foregoing is now included in [RichDEM's Python wrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/richdem). Documentation, with examples and pretty pictures, is available [here](https://richdem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/depression_filling.html).

[image: Depression-filling as performed on Beauford watershed]

(Disclaimer: I wrote the articles and code mentioned above.)

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, there is. I haven't tested yet, but I ran my eyes trough the source code. It seems a good program.

[Whitebox](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Landserf** (free to use) - [Click to Goto Homepage](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~jwo/landserf/)

I have used it, and love it.

I also think the algorithms are much more accurate in Landserf than in Arc, very very solid maths used and Jo Wood lists the maths used for his analysis.